# How these type (int (*ptr)[3]) = a; (where a is => int a[][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}) of statements work in C? Increment "ptr" gives unexpected result

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

For the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int (*ptr)[3] = a;
    printf("%d %d ", (*ptr)[1], (*ptr)[2]);
    ++ptr;
    printf("%d %d\n", (*ptr)[1], (*ptr)[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

what should it print? I am expecting:

> 2 3 3 4

but the output is:

> 2 3 5 6

I am expecting the output as `2 3 3 4` 
because initially the `ptr` is pointing to the first row of double dimensional array `a[][3]`. Therefore `(*ptr)[1]` of first printf will give us `2`, like wise `(*ptr)[2]` will give us `3`. But after the `++ptr` line it will start pointing to the second element of the first row of `a[][3]`. Therefore `(*ptr)[1]` of second line should now give us `3` and likewise `(*ptr)[2]` should give us `4`.

Comment: Why are you expecting  "2 3 3 4" output? It is hard to address the root your confusion without knowing where that root is.

Comment: This `int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};` should better be `int a[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};`.

Comment: @AnT I am expecting the output as "2 3 3 4" because I think initially the ptr is pointing to the first row of double dimensional array "a". Therefore **(*ptr)[1]** of first **printf** will give us **2**, like wise **(*ptr)[2]** will give us **3**. But after the **++ptr** line it will start pointing to the second element of the first row of **a[][3]**. Therefore **(*ptr)[1]** of second line should now give us **3** and likewise **(*ptr)[2]** should give us **4**.

Comment: Code like this would (probably) never pass a code review.

Comment: `ptr` is a *pointer to an array of int [3 of them]*. When you increment `ptr`, it will skip 3 `int`. So `ptr[0]` originally points to `1`, after increment it points to `4`.

Answer (score 7):

`ptr` is of type `int (*)[3]`:

```
int (*ptr)[3]
```

The type of `ptr` specifies how the *pointer airthmetic* is going to be performed on `ptr`.

---

For the following more general case:

```
int *p;
// ...
int (*ptr)[N] = p;
ptr += M; // same address as p[M * N]
```

Incrementing the pointer in `M` results in an address increment of `M * N * sizeof(int)` and not just `M * sizeof(int)` as you may have expected.

This is how pointer arithmetic works, because the type of the elements `ptr` points to is `int [N]` and not `int`.

---

After the statement `++ptr;` is executed, `ptr` points to the third element of `a`. The increment is done in steps of **three** elements of type `int` instead of a single one, that is, in your case, `N = 3`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's go through this line by line.

---

```
int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

`a` has the type "array of array of 3 `int`". This line is equivalent to

```
int a[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}; /* alternate */
```

It is clearer with this alternate line that `a` is an array of arrays. This will help with understanding the next lines.

```
int (*ptr)[3] = a;
```

`ptr` has the type "pointer to array of 3 `int`". Because of array-to-pointer decay, `ptr` will point to the first array in `a` (`int (*ptr)[3] = &a[0]`).

```
printf("%d %d ", (*ptr)[1], (*ptr)[2]);
```

Dereferencing `ptr` gives `a[0]`, so this will print

> 2 3

```
++ptr;
```

This seems to be where you are confused. Incrementing a pointer to an element makes the pointer point to where the next element would lie if they were in an array. In this case, the current element pointed to and the next element after that *are* in an array (the element being an array of 3 `int`s, not a single `int`). So incrementing the pointer makes it point to the next array of 3 `int`s (which happens to be `a[1]`).

```
printf("%d %d\n", (*ptr)[1], (*ptr)[2]);
```

Now that we know that `ptr` points to `a[1]`, we can see that `(*ptr)[1]` is equivalent to `a[1][1]`, which is 5; and that `(*ptr)[2]` is equivalent to `a[1][2]`, which is 6. So now the total output is:

> 2 3 5 6

---

Answer (score 3):

`(*ptr)[3]` is a **pointer** to an *array of three elements*. Below is an analysis of your program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int (*ptr)[3]=a;
    /* First note ptr is a pointer to an array of three integers
     * If you had written it like 
     * int (*ptr)[3];
     * ptr=&a[0];
     * ,it would have been more obvious.
     * But here, you have the freedom to use it interchangeably
     */

    printf("%d %d ", (*ptr)[1], (*ptr)[2]);
    /* Remember ptr is &a[0], so *ptr is dereferencing &a[0] to gets its value
     * However, since ptr is a pointer to an array, its value itself is an array
     * So you need to give the index like (*ptr)[1] & (*ptr)[2] to get the second and third values
     * (Mind the count starts with zero)
     * In essence you are doing,
     * printf("%d %d ", *((*ptr)+1*4*8),*((*ptr)+2*4*8)); // 4bytes=4*8 bits
     * Here '*ptr' will be substituted with a[0],the starting address an 12 byte block ( 3 integers * 4 bytes per integer)
     */
    ++ptr;
    /* Above step can be written as
     * ptr=ptr+1; 
     * This is pointer arithmetic, so '1' above should be considered as 1 block
     * Or in layman's terms move pointer to the next 12byte block.
     * In other words advance ptr by (12*8) bits so that it now points to &a[1]
     */
    printf("%d %d\n", (*ptr)[1], (*ptr)[2]);
    /* Follow the same steps for the first print with ptr is &a[1]
     */
    return 0;
}
```